# В чем суть использования в C++ stack и queue, если можно использовать vector, deque или list?

Tags: c++, vector, очередь, стек

Я только начал изучать C++, и у меня возник вопрос: зачем использовать stack и queue, если можно вместо них использовать vector, deque или list? Неужели так мешаются лишние функции или stack и queue работают быстрее?

Comment: Да хотя бы потому, что использование какого-нибудь вектора будет тянуть за собой возможность его использования не как стека :) Рассказывать в ответ о "самоограничении программиста" не стоит.

Comment: Для справки, что когда применять - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/how-can-i-efficiently-select-a-standard-library-container-in-c11

Comment: Работают не быстрее. Чтобы оставить задел на смену используемого внутри контейнера? Но мне это всегда казалось сомнительной идеей.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это прекрасная идея. Например DFS и BFS - один и тот же алгоритм если менять стек на очередь.

Comment: Это не вопрос производительности. Это вопрос простоты и выразительности. Если в коде написано `stack` я не буду ждать что кто-то обратиться к его среднему элементу. Пока код прост - это не важно. Чем сложнее код, тем важнее чтобы кирпичики из которых он складывается были или казались простыми.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я немного не про это, все-таки у стека и очереди интерфейс отличается. Я про то, что у очереди (или стека) можно менять начинку-контейнер.